# Converting disk image files

Tags: conversion, iso-image, file-format, disk-image

Is there some kind of application for converting between various formats of disk image files (.img, .iso, ...)?

Comment: img and iso are the same, just raw image with no meta data, but there are more formats ofc

Comment: @Joakim - Yes, of course. But, I just putted these as an example, because when I first worded the letter I forgot to say that I ment *disk* image files, so some assumed (logically) I ment pictures.

Comment: Check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ISO_image_software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/) can do that. Not free though...

> **Simple and Intelligent**
>
> MagicISO is a powerful CD/DVD image
>   file creating/editing/extracting tool.
>   It can open / create / edit /extract
>   CD/DVD image files, and it can convert
>   bin to iso and back.  as well as make
>   ISO file from DVD/CD-ROM or hard disk,
>   and handle bootable information at
>   meanwhile.
>
> **Support all known CD image type**
>
> It can also convert BIN or any other
>   format file created by CD burning
>   software (Such as Nero-Burning ROM,
>   Easy CD Create) or virtual DVD/CD-ROM
>   driver software (such as Daemon-tools)
>   to standard ISO format.

Comment: MagicISO is not free as in "free software", but they do have a [freeware virtual CD-ROM called MagicDisc](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm) which allowed me to convert an IMG file into an ISO (that is, by opening the IMG file as a virtual CD, then saving it as ISO), which I could then read/mount using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/).

> Convert image files between ISO/BIN and other formats. PowerISO can convert almost all image file formats to standard ISO format file.